# Пересечение движущихся сфер

Tags: c#, unity3d, графика, геометрия

Добрый день.
Помогите пожалуйста с решением проблемы:
Есть Функция нахождения пересечения двух отрезков, результат функции - t0, t1, distanceSqr.

Для пересечение двух сфер я использую

```
LineDistance distance = LineSegment.DistanceSqr(A, B, C, D);

float r2 = (a.Radius + a.Radius) * (b.Radius + b.Radius);
if (distance.DistanceSqr <= r2)
Vector3 moveDir = (B - A) * distance.T;
```

точка пересечения = `A + moveDir;`
Теперь эту точку я хочу сдвинуть на столько, что бы сфера касалась края отрезка CD и делаю:

```
A + moveDir - moveDir.normalized * Mathf.Sqrt(r2 - distance.DistanceSqr);
```

Все хорошо, когда отрезки перпендикулярны:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда появляется угол между отрезками, расстояние становится не правильным:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня не получается решить данную проблему.
Что нужно посчитать\дописать чтобы учитывать это смещение?

Comment: Если нужно смещение, можно попробовать взять (90/диаметр_сферы*угол_наклона_в_градусах). Но, лучше подойти к вопросу со стороны кватернионов и векторов. Можете пояснить, где точки A,B,C,D на скрине?

Comment: @test123
http://savepic.ru/14847705.png

Comment: Замените картинку в вопросе, на ту, что в комментарии. Возьмите отрезок, параллельный DC на расстоянии суммы радиусов сфер, и считайте пересечение с ним без смещений. Надеюсь получение параллельного отрезка на нужном расстоянии проблемы не составит.

Comment: @rdorn
Получить паралельный отрезок:
`(D - С).normalized * Mathf.Sqrt(r2 - distance.DistanceSqr)`
Вы про это?
и как посчитать пересечение с ним?

Comment: также, как вы считали пересечение с DC, только не добавлять поправку. И что-то мне подсказывает, что это не даст вам параллельный отрезок, точнее даст, но не на нужном расстоянии. К сожалению не силен в unity, но неплохо помню геометрию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам по сути нужно найти расстояние между центром паралеллограмма-пересечения и центром касающейся окружности (и на это расстояние надо отступить назад от точки `A + moveDir`).

Для этого рассмотрим подобные серые треугольники:

[image: иллюстрация]

Вертикальные катеты у них равны соответствующим радиусам окружностей, а гипотенузы — тем же катетам, делённым на синус угла между отрезками.

Итого, расстояние, на которое нужно отойти назад, равно `(a.Radius + b.Radius) / Mathf.Sin(alpha)`, где `alpha` — угол между отрезками.

---

Синус угла можно найти как `Mathf.Sqrt(1 - cosA * cosA)`, где `double cosA = Vector3.Dot((B - A).normalized, (D - C).normalized)`. Итого:

```
double cosA = Vector3.Dot((B - A).normalized, (D - C).normalized);
double stepBack = (a.Radius + b.Radius) / Mathf.Sqrt(1 - cosA * cosA);
```

Comment: Вот, что получилось в результате:
http://savepic.ru/14910473.png

@VladD

`float cosA = Vector3.Dot((B - A).normalized, (D - С).normalized);
float alpha = Mathf.Sqrt(1 - cosA * cosA);
float tt = (a.Radius + b.Radius) / Mathf.Sin(alpha);

res = A + moveDir - moveDir.normalized * tt;`

Comment: Получилось сделать:
http://savepic.ru/14880799.htm

`float angle = Vector3.Angle((B - A).normalized, (D - C).normalized) * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
res = A + moveDir - moveDir.normalized * ((a.Radius + b.Radius) / Mathf.Sin(angle))`

Но возникла другая проблема:
http://savepic.ru/14936080.png

Comment: @Zed: Не, первая формула неверна: `Mathf.Sqrt(1 - cosA * cosA)` — это не `alpha`, это синус `alpha`. Нужно было просто `float tt = (a.Radius + b.Radius) / alpha;`

Comment: А вторую проблему не понял. Вам нужно отдельное поведение, когда отрезки не пересекаются? Какое? Специфицируйте.

Comment: @Zed: Непонятно, можете показать результат с двумя разными углами? (И с углом 90 градусов тоже.) И да, это по первой проблеме, или по второй?

Comment: Теперь получается чем больше угол - тем больше расстояние. 
http://savepic.ru/14907429.png
http://savepic.ru/14928932.png

Его нужно каким-то образом не учитывать.
Может считать угол до от результирующей точки?

Comment: С первой проблемой разобрался. @VladD
`float cosA = Vector3.Dot((B - A).normalized, (В - С).normalized);
float alpha = Mathf.Sqrt((r2 - distance.DistanceSqr) / (1 - cosA * cosA));
res = A + moveDir - moveDir.normalized * alpha;`
Большое спасибо.
Осталось решить новую проблему.

Comment: @Zed: Ага, я так и написал в обновлении ответа.

Comment: А по второй проблеме, мне кажется, лучше задать отдельный вопрос.